# How to insert html code on the page (with DOCTYPE)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, highlight.js

Inserting code with DOCTYPE is not possible.
For highlight i use highlight.js

I tried:

```
document.querySelectorAll("code").forEach(function(element) {
        element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;").replace(/"/g, "&quot;").replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
    });
```

HTML:

```
<pre><code class="html"><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper"></div>
  </body>
</html></code></pre>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you are writing invalid HTML, converting it to a DOM (by loading the HTML document) which performs error recovery, and then trying to convert the DOM back to HTML.

That is going to give you an HTML representation of what the browser recovered from your errors and not the original code.

You should write the HTML correctly in the first place, and not try to fix it with JavaScript later.

```html
<pre><code class="html">&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;
&lt;html&gt;
  &lt;body&gt;
    &lt;div class="wrapper"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
  &lt;/body&gt;
&lt;/html&gt;</code></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it with a textarea, then, copy the text from the textarea, and set it as the innerHTML of your code element.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("code textarea").forEach(function(element) {
  element.parentElement.innerHTML = element.innerHTML;

});
```

```html
<pre>
<code class="html">
<textarea>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <p>Works</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
</textarea>
</code>
</pre>
```